# Breaking a XOR with repeating key and counter

Tags: cryptography, xor

I was given an exercise where I have to break a xor with repeating key and counter.
I don't know the key nor its length, nor the value of the counter.

I have:

```
PT1 xor K = C1 
PT2 xor K = C2 
PT3 xor K = C3
```

So:

```
C1 xor C2 = PT1 xor PT2 xor K xor K = PT1 xor PT2 xor 0
```

So:

```
0 xor C1 xor C2 = PT1 xor PT2
0 xor C1 xor C3 = PT1 xor PT3
0 Xor C2 xor C3 = PT2 xor PT3
```

Where K is key, C is cypher and PT is Plain Text.

I don't know what to do with that. Could you please give me a hint? :)

Comment: I don't see a counter, and I don't see a key *with unknown length* either.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk That's a weird middle name. I'm talking of course about "Reinstate", not "Monica", I'm rather afraid to say anything about that :)

Comment: The key with unknow length is K

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that satisfies your conditions from with your question

```
PT1(5)   K(9)   C1(12)
PT2(7)   K(9)   C2(14)
PT3(9)   K(9)   C3(0)

0 xor C1 xor C2 = PT1 xor PT2
0 xor C1 xor C3 = PT1 xor PT3
0 Xor C2 xor C3 = PT2 xor PT3

So in the case i built:
0 xor C1(12) xor C2(14) = PT1(5) xor PT2(7)
0 xor C1(12) xor C3(0) =  PT1(5) xor PT3(9)
0 Xor C2(14) xor C3(0) =  PT2(7) xor PT3(9)
```

In weak cases you can get K like this:

You can get K like this:

```
In [519]: 1^5                                                                                                                                  
Out[519]: 4

In [520]: 2^5                                                                                                                                  
Out[520]: 7

In [521]: 3^5                                                                                                                                  
Out[521]: 6

In [522]: 6^7^4                                                                                                                                
Out[522]: 5
```

So you can crack the key by xoring the ciphers together if a weak key to xor cipher is used ( Does not work in all cases only very rare one ). But does that help any for helping you solve the problem?

```
PT1 xor K = C1   if c1 is 4
PT2 xor K = C2   if c2 is 7
PT3 xor K = C3   if c2 is 6
```

You know that K is 5. From there you can get PT by working the XOR backwards:

```
c1 (4) ^ K (5) = PT1
c2 (7) ^ K (5) = PT2
c3 (6) ^ K (5) = PT3
```

So to recap, XOR c1^c2^c3 to get K, and from there you can get the corresponding PT(1-3). But this only works in some rare cases, but does it help?

If you have any of the values, let me know. I'll try to recreate something from scratch

Here's a case where i XORED the C1, C2, C3 together to get a key, and then PT1-3 just fill in to work

```
PT1(10)  K(12)   C1(6)
PT2(4)   K(12)   C2(8)
PT3(14)  K(12)   C3(2)


0 xor C1(6) xor C2(8) =  PT1(10) xor PT2(4)    
0 xor C1(6) xor C3(2) =  PT1(10) xor PT3(14)  
0 Xor C2(8) xor C3(2) =  PT2(4)  xor PT3(14)
```

It really depends on how your assignment is expecting you to get the key. I hope all of this helps, encryption is fun. I provided a few paths, hopefully one will help.

Comment: I've only got the cipher text. But I think this will help :) thanks!